# LiftWeb on Production

Tags: jetty, lift, production-environment

I'm planning to deploy a web service based on LiftWeb (and Jetty) and was wondering what would be the most appropriate solution for that (in the term of process host).

The first solution I can think of is a Linux Daemon which executes Jetty and my service. Another option would be to run it from command line (JAVA ...).

I'll be glad to know if anybody experienced difficulties with one of the above solutions or have other alternative for that.

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 0):

Jetty has a setuid option available as well, it is packaged in the jetty-hightide distribution and is also available as artifacts in maven central.

http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-hightide/

Answer (score 0):

My solution is run`sbt package` in the console,and copy the WAR file to the jetty/webapps/root.war.
https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Apache_and_Jetty_Configuration